# Filter a map value using java 8 streams

Tags: java-8

I have a map as below and wanted to retrieve the values of the inner map using the key.

```
<bean id="testMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
      <map>
        <entry key="A" value="AA" />
        <entry key="B">
          <map>
            <entry key="B1" value="B11" />
            <entry key="B2" value="B22" />
            <entry key="B3" value="B33" />
          </map>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

below code prints the 1st level, how to print the inner map value?

```
myMap.entrySet().stream().filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("B")).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
```

Comment: [`.flatmap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) after the `filter`

Comment: @RobinTopper could u please provide sample code with .flatMap()

Answer (score 2):

The answer is less straightforward than the one most people with a nested map are looking for because you have a `Map<String,Object>`.

Recreating the map you describe:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> bMap = new HashMap<>();
bMap.put("B1", "B11");
bMap.put("B2", "B22");
bMap.put("B3", "B33");

map.put("A", "AA");
map.put("B", bMap);
```

Then getting the values of the inner map:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("B"))
   .flatMap(entry -> ((Map<String,String>) entry.getValue()).values().stream())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints:

```
B22
B33
B11
```

---

A shorter and faster solution was provided by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) in the comments:

```
((Map<String,String>)map.get("B")).values().stream() 
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It does a single lookup of the map entry instead of the linear search in the above solution, i.e. it is faster.

Comment: How about `((Map<String,String>)map.get("B")).values().stream() .forEach(System.out::println);`?

Comment: …and does a single lookup rather than a linear search.

Comment: You may add it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?
     `myMap
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("B"))
    .values().forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));`

Comment: [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) doesn't have a `values()` method

Comment: is that a question or an answer ?